# Using Ray Core Actors on multiple cpu core at same time

Tags: openmp, distributed-computing, ray

I am trying to use Ray Core for communication between nodes for multinode clusters. The problem is that, one Ray actor can only work on one core at a time, and the C++ APIs I'm calling from the python are using openmp for loop optimization. So, the loop optimization is becoming redundant. I need to use Ray Core such that I could use those loop optimization.

One more approach I am thinking of is to use Ray Actors just for communication between nodes and start another process which can run my program in background on that process where I can use openmp parallelization. But till now, not able to find any lead on that.

Could anyone suggest some solution/approaches for this problem?

Comment: Look into OMP tasks. You could spawn a bunch of them, and give each task one actor. (Note: I have no idea what Ray Core is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the python environment variable 'OMP_NUM_THREADS' is set to 1 by default, and even after increasing the num_cpus to K>1, 'OMP_NUM_THREADS' remain to be 1. If we explicitly change the 'OMP_NUM_THREADS' variable with something like export OMP_NUM_THREADS="10",  it works. That is, openmp runs behind the ray actor.